# Routing pandas dataframe in Flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have assigned a pandas dataframe globally

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

I have a Flask app with a submit route that's triggered once user makes a POST request from the browser.

```
@app.route('/submit')
def sub():
   // do some filtering in df

   return redirect(url_for('recommend', uid=1))
```

I would like `sub()` to pass df to `/recommend`.

```
@app.route('/recommend/<int uid>')
def rec(uid):
   // make recommendations based on df

   return df.to_html()
```

The problem is, how do I pass it? I've tried passing it in the URL query

```
@app.route('/submit')
def sub():
   // do some filtering in df

   return redirect(url_for('recommend', uid=1, df=df))

@app.route('/recommend/<int uid>/<df>')
def rec(uid,df):
   // make recommendations based on df

   return df.to_html()
```

But this turns `df` to a string. I thought the path of least resistance would be to just make `df` global, but any local manipulations to `df` inside `sub()` are not getting picked up globally.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning df as global is not an effective solution in most cases. There are many ways you can use a dataframe across different methods/routes in a flask application: sessions, pickling, converting df to csv/json/dict, or returning it through a function, etc. depending on your dataframe and what you intend to do with it.
Here are few examples:

```
def filter-df():
   df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
   // do some filtering in df
   return df

@app.route('/submit')
def sub():
   // or you can use session/pickling to cache/store your df after you do some filtering in df
   return redirect(url_for('recommend', uid=1))

@app.route('/recommend/<int uid>')
def rec(uid):
   df = filter-df()
   // make recommendations based on df
   return df.to_html()
```

Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43302961/11745574) on how to use session and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64383174/11745574) one on how to pickle/unpickle.

Answer (score 0):

while setting -   session['dataframe'] =x.to_json()

while reading -  df_data = pd.read_json(session['dataframe'])

Comment: Please explain how this helps.